# Php mysqli->real_escape_string and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-real-escape-string

I've a little question.
I've written this code to add the values to mysql database but when i run the code and I got an error. Can anybody help me?

the code:

```
$fel = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO deleted (uid,buy_type,prop_type,district,street,room_min,room_max,price_min,price_max,condition_type,heat_type,lift_type,parking_type,type_of_del,when)  
                            VALUES ('".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['uid'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['buy_type'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['prop_type'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['district'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['street'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['room_min'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['room_max'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['price_min'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['price_max'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['condition_type'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['heat_type'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['lift_type'])."',
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($letomb['parking_type']).",
                                    '".$mysqli->real_escape_string($type_of_del)."', 
                                    now())") or die($mysqli->error);
```

Error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'when) VALUES ('3', 'kiado', 'lakas', '1'' at line 1
```

Answer (score 2):

`WHEN` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). Enclosing it in backticks should fix your problem, as it will then be treated as an [identifier](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/identifiers.html).

```
`when`
```

Comment: Ok I've corrected that issue with this code and i go that error:

Answer (score 1):

You should use backticks around your column names. `when` is a MySQL keyword so it's being interpreted incorrectly. At the very least use backticks around `when`.